# Parametros de una busqueda con páginación

Tags: laravel-5

En una página hecha en Laravel necesito hacer un filtro de los productos y mostrarlos con una paginacion.
Cuando busco con un criterio (Ejemplo : ./criterio?type=4) y le doy siguiente quita el tipo del criterio y deja la pagina (Ejemplo: ./criterio?page=2). 
Tuve que editar la paginacion porque si no hay una pag antes o despues se coloca la pagina de inicio.
Como le puedo hacer para que mantenga el tipo del criterio?
Adjunto lo que tengo como paginacion

https://jsfiddle.net/ykv7n22v/

Resuelto:
Agrege en las url esto

```
{{ $globos->nextPageUrl().'&type='.app('request')->input('type') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de hacer, en cada llamada a una url concatenar el filtro:

```
{{ $globos->nextPageUrl() . "type="  .$request->get('type') }}
```

Comment: Pero si no hay que pasaría? no marca error?

Comment: Si no hay que cosa? tu paginación te debe de arrojar la cantidad de opciones basadas en el criterio por lo que no debería eso generarte problema.

Comment: Perdón, si no hay nexPageUrl() o type

Comment: No te va a afectar si no hay nextPageUrl() porque en tu código tu pones que eso se mostrará únicamente si hay páginas adicionales; tampoco te afectará  el parámetro en la url porque se aplica dentro del filtro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera.
`{{ $globos->nextPageUrl().'&type='.app('request')->input('type') }}`